# Clean Up This WebScrape?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

My code goes into this website, and scrapes the title and author (**individually**).

Ideally, id want each row to store its information in a dictionary.

*For example if we look at row 3 on the website - I want to scrape the Title and the Author.*

However my code cannot scrape "by row". Meaning I dont know how to scrape these fields per row to put into a dictionary.

EDIT- The Author and Title of each row would be added to the dictionary/list. So picture a for-loop for each row, and for each row we want the Title and the Author

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
dt=[]
driver = webdriver.Chrome()


url='https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/session/13619'
driver.get(url)
page_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source,'html.parser')
time.sleep(2)

eachTitle=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='record__title ng-star-inserted']")
for i in eachTitle:
    title=(i.text)
    print(title)
    dict = {"title": title} #current Dictionary

eachAuthor=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='record__ellipsis']")
for j in eachAuthor:
    try:
        author=(j.text)
    except:
        author='No author Found' #some rows dont have authors, like row 1 and 2.
    print(author)#Add author to the dictionary above as well?
```

Comment: You can cheat if the lengths of eachTitle and eachAuthor are the same and if you get them both in the correct order by using zip: `for (i, j) in zip(eachTitle, eachAuthor): ...`.

Comment: would each author be a list? A concatenated string? Separate columns? Also, 1 and 2 don't appear to be presentations despite title. Aren't they chairing the whole thing?

Comment: @QHarr The Author and Title of each row would be added to the dictionary. So picture a for-loop for each row, and for each row we want the Title and the Author.

Comment: But where there is a more than one author what goes into the dictionary? A list of authors? A comma separated string concatenation of them?

Comment: @QHarr Yes please, if more than 1 author, then they can all be concatenated or seperated by comma. Does not really matter. In row 3, there are multiple authors. It does not matter if there are multiple. As long as the information is pulled in a row by row basis

Comment: @QHarr example below shows good example of how the author/title output should look like. The website is static however :l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just get the dictionary/json directly where that data is present.

```
import requests

session_ids = ['13619' ,'13736']

for session_id in session_ids:
    url = 'https://cdn-solr.asco.org/solr/ml/mlselect'
    payload = '?_format=json&wt=json&indent=true&q=SessionId:' + session_id + '&start=0&rows=30&sort=score%20desc,%20SessionId%20asc&fq=RecordType:sessions&facet=true&f.Year.facet.sort=index&facet.field={!key=Year}Year&facet.field={!key=subject_thes}subject_thes&facet.field={!key=MediaTypes}MediaTypes&facet.field={!key=fctSessionType}fctSessionType&facet.pivot={!key=MeetingName}fctMeetingName,fctTrack&spellcheck.maxCollationTries=100'
    headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36'}
    
    jsonData = requests.get(url+payload, headers=headers).json()
    sessionParticipationID = jsonData['response']['docs'][0]['SessionParticipationID']
    session_id_list = '%20OR%20'.join(sessionParticipationID)
    
    
    payload = '?_format=json&wt=json&indent=true&sort=PresentationOrderWithinSession%20asc,%20ISODateString%20asc,%20ISODateStringEnd%20asc&fl=_id,%20score,%20ISODateString,%20ISODateStringEnd,%20ISODateString_1,%20ISODateStringEnd_1,%20Year,%20Title,%20tempAbstractID,%20MediaID,%20VideoID,%20EdBookID,%20edBookTitle,%20PosterID,%20edBookTitle,%20SessionTitle,%20SessionTypeId,%20AuthorString,%20AbstID,%20Role,%20FullName,%20PosterBoard,%20Institution,%20ProgramTitle,%20MeetingName,%20FirstAuthor&q=_id:(' + session_id_list + ')&rows=' + str(len(sessionParticipationID))
    
    jsonData = requests.get(url+payload, headers=headers).json()
    
    title_auth = []  #<-- to make a list of {title:author} dictionary
    for each in jsonData['response']['docs']:
        title = each['Title']
        author = each['AuthorString']
        
        title_auth.append({title:author})  #<-- to make a list of {title:author} dictionary
        print('Title: %s\nAuthor(s): %s\n\n' %(title, author))
```

**Output:**

```
Title: Chair - Developmental Therapeutics—Molecularly Targeted Agents and Tumor Biology
Author(s): 


Title: Chair - Developmental Therapeutics—Molecularly Targeted Agents and Tumor Biology
Author(s): 


Title: A first-in-human phase 1 study of a novel PARP7 inhibitor RBN-2397 in patients with advanced solid tumors.
Author(s): Gerald S. Falchook, Manish R. Patel, Timothy A. Yap, Kristen McEachern, Kristy Kuplast-Barr, Luke Utley, Lisa Cleary, Erika Manyak, Viviana Bozon, Sudha Parasuraman, Melissa L. Johnson


Title: First-in-human biomarker-driven phase I trial of the potent and selective glutaminase-1 (GLS1) inhibitor IACS-6274 (IPN60090) in patients (pts) with molecularly selected advanced solid tumors.
Author(s): Timothy A. Yap, Ecaterina E. Dumbrava, Jordi Rodon Ahnert, David S. Hong, Shubham Pant, Daniel D. Karp, Sarina Anne A. Piha-Paul, Vivek Subbiah, Apostolia M. Tsimberidou, Siqing Fu, Filip Janku, Sandra Montez, Majd T. Ahmad-Taha, Darlene Guerrero, Natalya N. Nazarenko, Yan Moore, Michael Soth, Jeff Kovacs, Timothy P. Heffernan, Philip Jones


Title: Phase 2 study of DRD2 antagonist/ClpP agonist ONC201 in neuroendocrine tumors.
Author(s): Peter M. Anderson, Janette Gortz


Title: New Directions in Targeting Metabolism and Stress Response
Author(s): 


Title: Panel Question and Answer with Drs. Kachnic, Cote, Falchook, Yap, Anderson and Owen
Author(s): 


Title: Efficacy and safety of zenocutuzumab in advanced pancreas cancer and other solid tumors harboring NRG1 fusions.
Author(s): Alison M. Schram, Eileen M. O'Reilly, Grainne M. O'Kane, Koichi Goto, Dong-Wan Kim, Cindy Neuzillet, Patricia Martin-Romano, Michaël Duruisseaux, Misako Nagasaka, Jordi Rodon, Benjamin A. Weinberg, Kumiko Umemoto, Sai-Hong I. Ou, Teresa Macarulla, Christelle De La Fouchardiere, Andrew K. Joe, Ernesto Wasserman, Viktoriya Stalbovskaya, Jim Ford


Title: MyPathway HER2 basket study: Pertuzumab (P) + trastuzumab (H) treatment of a large, tissue-agnostic cohort of patients with HER2-positive advanced solid tumors.
Author(s): Funda Meric-Bernstam, John Hainsworth, Ron Bose, Howard A. Burris III, Claire F. Friedman, Razelle Kurzrock, Charles Swanton, Yong Wang, Jonathan Levy, Katja Schulze, Richard Price, Arisha Patel, Christopher Sweeney


Title: Initial results from a dose finding study of TNO155, a SHP2 inhibitor, in adults with advanced solid tumors.
Author(s): Irene Brana, Geoffrey Shapiro, Melissa L. Johnson, Helena A. Yu, Debbie Robbrecht, Daniel S. Tan, Lillian L. Siu, Hironobu Minami, Neeltje Steeghs, Thomas Hengelage, Eugene Tan, Kelly Biette, Kun Xu, Susan E. Moody, Maria Jove


Title: HER2: A SHP(2) That Hasn't Sailed
Author(s): 


Title: Panel Question and Answer with Drs. Kachnic, Cote, Schram, Meric-Bernstam, Brana, and Garrido-Laguna
Author(s): 


Title: First-in-human phase I/II study of CYT-0851, a first-in-class inhibitor of RAD51-mediated homologous recombination in patients with advanced solid and hematologic cancers.
Author(s): Ryan Lynch, Johanna C. Bendell, Ranjana H. Advani, Gerald S. Falchook, Pamela N. Munster, Manish R. Patel, Martin Gutierrez, Monika L. Burness, Neil Palmisiano, Mehdi Hamadani, William D. Bradley, Thomas J. O'Shea, Susan Doleman, Markus F. Renschler, Judson M. Englert, Timothy A. Yap


Title: A phase Ib trial of belvarafenib in combination with cobimetinib in patients with advanced solid tumors: Interim results of dose-escalation and patients with NRAS-mutant melanoma of dose-expansion.
Author(s): Sang Joon Shin, Jeeyun Lee, Tae Min Kim, Jin-Soo Kim, Yu Jung Kim, Yong Sang Hong, Sun Young Kim, Jeong Eun Kim, Dae Ho Lee, Yoon-hee Hong, Young Su Noh, Song Kim, Eunhye Baek, SuJin Jung, Paul Rhee, Jinjoo Kim, Jennifer Eng-Wong, Vikram Malhi, Sharareh Monemi, Tae Won Kim


Title: BOS172738, a highly potent and selective RET inhibitor, for the treatment of <em>RET</em>-altered tumors including <em>RET</em>-fusion+ NSCLC and <em>RET</em>-mutant MTC: Phase 1 study results.
Author(s): Patrick Schoffski, Byoung Chul Cho, Antoine Italiano, Herbert H. Loong, Christophe Massard, Laura Medina Rodriguez, Jin-Yuan Shih, Vivek Subbiah, Loic Verlingue, Karen Andreas, Craig T. Basson, Alicia Clawson, Peter T. Ho, Shelley Knight, Anita Scheuber, Mitchell Keegan


Title: New Twists on Old Targets
Author(s): 


Title: Panel Question and Answer with Drs. Kachnic, Cote, Lynch, Shin, Schoffski, and Vaishampayan
Author(s):
```

Comment: The payload variable - Id eventually use this code in a for loop for other pages and that payload variable looks like it only applies to this webpage. For example, URL https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/session/13736 is another webpage. And so on. How can we fix the payload variable so it applies to any URL i put for the URL variable in my original code

Comment: It's by changing the `q=_id`. Let me see if that gets somewhere that we can input that in

Comment: Would this be of any help? api_url = "example/{id}"
    id_ = URL.split("/")[-1] #to get the ID
    each= requests.get(api_url.format(id=id_)).json()

Comment: as long as you have that sesison id you can get each of the presentation ids to then feed in. I adjusted the code. I don't have time today, but I can slightly clean this up a bit, but overall, does get what you need.

Comment: can i ask where you got AuthorString and Title from? I went to the json page and could not find these variables?

Comment: It’s in each element in a list with keys/path ‘['response']['docs']’

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231715/discussion-between-void-s-and-chitown88).

Comment: I did a CTRL F into the json page and could not find them?